# Insert new rows into table that's connected to another table on Database

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have two tables in a `Database`: Menu and Companies. Both are connected by the `CompanyID`. In the `company` table there are nearly 100 rows of information on different companies. 
I can insert one row into the Menu table by this `sql` `query`:

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`CompanyID`, `MenuName`, `MenuLink`, `ImageLink`,
`ListOrder`, `Popup`, `ParentMenuID`, `IsActive`, `IsAdmin`) VALUES
('11', 'Holidays', 'lookups/Holidays.aspx', 'images/Archive.png', '11',
'1', '1807', '1', '0');
```

I set the `CompanyID` to 11 here. But I don't want to do an insert `query` for each CompanyID so if there a way to insert for all the companies?

Comment: For the conditional insert look up the CASE WHEN THEN syntax

Comment: @KarmaEDV I'm going to use use two separate queries. What do I need for the update query to change the ParentMenuID?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you... T-SQL sysntax: update menu set ParentMenuID = case when menulink like '%lookups%' then companyid else parentmenuid end where companyid = @companyid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO menu (CompanyID
, MenuName
, MenuLink
, ImageLink
, ListOrder
, Popup
, ParentMenuID
, IsActive
, IsAdmin) 
SELECT CompanyID
, 'Holidays'
, 'lookups/Holidays.aspx'
, 'images/Archive.png'
, '11'
, '1'
, '1807'
, '1'
, '0'
FROM companies
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I forgot a part in my question. Could you please see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

`Try This one`

`INSERT INTO menu (CompanyID, MenuName, MenuLink, ImageLink, ListOrder, Popup, ParentMenuID, IsActive, IsAdmin) 
SELECT CompanyID, 'Holidays', 'lookups/Holidays.aspx', 'images/Archive.png'
, '11', '1', '1807', '1', '0' FROM companies`

> Note : Replace these (CompanyID, 'Holidays', 'lookups/Holidays.aspx', 'images/Archive.png', '11', '1', '1807', '1', '0') fields with correspondence fields in side companies table